# Get Google Emailer Script To Run For A Specific Set of Tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I have an emailer script that I would like to run for specified tabs and also make sure it skips any rows with blank values as it currently seems to break down as soon as it hits a blank row.

I have successfully built the script to work for one tab, but it seems to break down as soon as I try and get it to work for multiple tabs.

```
function reminders() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET-ID");
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(("sheet_1","sheet_2","sheet_3")));
 var editedCell = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
 var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var text1 = 'Insert body of email here';
 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
   (function(val) {
     var row = data[i];
     var recipient = row[4];
     var name = row[2];
     var replyto = 'reply_to@email.com';
     var body = 'Dear' + ' ' + name + ',' + '\n\n' + text1;
     var subject = 'Hello World';
     GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {from:'reply_to@email.com', replyto:'reply_to@email.com'});
   })(i);
}
```

This currently works for sheet_1 but does not work for sheet_2 or sheet_3.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can improve this script to send to multiple sheets and also skip blank rows?

Answer (score 1):

- You want to send emails using the values of column "C" and "E" from the Spreadsheet.
- You want to run your script for the sheet names of "sheet_1", "sheet_2" and "sheet_3".
- You want to skip the rows which have no values of the column "C" and/or "E".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- It seems that when `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(("sheet_1","sheet_2","sheet_3")));` is run, only "sheet_3" is retrieved.

  - In your case, I think that `setActiveSheet()` might not be required to be used.
- Number of arguments of `getSheetByName(("sheet_1","sheet_2","sheet_3"))` is one.

  - When you want to use multiple sheets, please use each sheet name in the loop.
- `var editedCell = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();` is not used in your script.
- `val` of `(function(val) {` is not used in your script.
- When you want to skip the empty rows, please put the if statement before `GmailApp.sendEmail()`. By this, the error is removed at `GmailApp.sendEmail()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following modified script to the script editor.

```
function reminders() {
  var sheets = ["sheet_1","sheet_2","sheet_3"]; // Please set the sheet names here.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET-ID");
  for (var s = 0; s < sheets.length; s++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[s]);
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var text1 = 'Insert body of email here';
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = data[i];
      var recipient = row[4];
      var name = row[2];
      if (!recipient || !name) continue; // Here, the empty rows are skipped.
      var replyto = 'reply_to@email.com';
      var body = 'Dear' + ' ' + name + ',' + '\n\n' + text1;
      var subject = 'Hello World';
      GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {from:'reply_to@email.com', replyto:'reply_to@email.com'});
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when "recipient" or "name" are not existing, the row is skipped.
- When you send a lot of emails, please be careful the quotas of "Email read/write". You can see it at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.